# How to get CMakeLists.txt to call a clean target on an external project (Makefile)?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, cmakelists-options

I am installing some firmware that needs to be compiled and installed with make by CMake, this is done via ExternalProject_Add in the CMakeLists.txt.

This is what I have in the CMakeLists.txt

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(<PACKAGE_NAME>
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<SOME_PATH>
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    BUILD_COMMAND $(MAKE)
    INSTALL_COMMAND $(MAKE) DESTDIR=${<PACKAGE>_DESTDIR} install
)
```

This works as intended, but when I need to call cmake clean, the binaries for the external project are not cleaned and causes problems when compiling again. Is there some way to manually add the Makefile clean target to CMakeLists.txt?